# Using byVal in C#..... a little complicated

Tags: c#, vb.net

In VB

```
   Protected Overridable ReadOnly Property AuthorizationHeaderValue(ByVal signature As       String) As String
Get
    Return String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", AuthorizationHeaderSignaturePrefix, APIIdentifier, signature)
End Get
End Property
```

What I have in C#:

```
    protected virtual string AuthorizationHeaderValue
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", AuthorizationHeaderSignaturePrefix, APIIdentifier, signature); }
    }
```

I am getting this error in C#:

> *The name 'signature' does not exist in the current context...*

which to me seems obvious since when I convert the code it drops the (`ByVal signature as String`).

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your C# code is that the property body expects a variable *signature* but you do not define a variable with that name.

C# does not allow properties to have parameters as VB.Net does (except for one [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) per class).  Consider converting it to a method.

```
protected virtual string AuthorizationHeaderValue(string signature)
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", AuthorizationHeaderSignaturePrefix, 
          APIIdentifier, signature);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking along these lines.  Too bad c sharp doesn't allow for this, it's a powerful aspect of VB.NET.

Comment: I disagree... it makes properties ambiguous between methods.  A major advantage to properties is the performance... however you lose this when you add a parameter.

Comment: Let's hope the code actually works.  I've got about 15 more errors to figure out. :p

Comment: What would I do for a set command?

        public string DataField
        {
            get
            {
                string field = string.Empty;
                _dataFieldLookup.TryGetValue(headerValue, field);
                return field;
            }
            set { _dataFieldLookup(headerValue) = value; }
        }

Comment: If you need to both get and set, I suggest `string GetAuthorizationHeaderValue(string signature)` and `void SetAuthorizationHeaderValue(string headerValue, string signature)`